# db2_escape_string replacement function for db2 on i

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

PHP's db2_escape_string() function uses a backslash `\` as an escape character. For whatever reason, my instance of DB2 on i expects an apostrophe `'` when escaping a string. My solution so far has been str_replace():

```
str_replace("'", "''", $var);
```

But that's getting pretty tedious. I'm using codeigniter, which has a db2 on i driver (db2c, if you're interested), which has a _prep_query() function, which could escape all my statements before execution, but I don't know what to replace db2_escape_string() with. I assume there exists some ridiculous preg_replace() function that would solve my problem, but my regex skills are terrible. I don't even know where to begin.

Alternatively, if someone knows how to change the escape character in DB2 on i to a backslash, that would solve my problem . . . or if we could ban apostrophes from the English language.

Comment: Turns out the db2c driver is mis-using db2_escape_string(), BUT db2_escape_string() is now working properly on my server. I did some tests yesterday, and it's using apostrophes as it should. The problem is that the driver uses that function to escape the <i>entire query</i>, right before db2_exec is called. Of course this would cause the query to fail. In the spirit of "do it right the first time", I'm going with @Leons answer. I have a lot of coding to do. Thanks for the quality answers. I couldn't do my job without stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using prepared statements ([db2_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-prepare.php), followed by [db2_execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-execute.php)) instead of raw sql (db2_exec) as a way of avoiding the string escape problem. The parameters you pass into db2_execute will be automatically escaped in the correct way.

If you are running into encoding issues, [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) might help.

Prepared statements prevent the possibility of hostile SQL injection. In DB2, they also let you insert more than 32k of data at a time.

Comment: Good advice. Unfortunately, the codeigniter driver structure doesn't appear to support prepared statements. Could be my ignorance. I think that, in the long run, this is the correct solution. It's just going to require some significant changes to the db driver functionality in codeigniter, or replacing it with my own db driver implementation . . .

Answer (score 0):

Would definitely be better if you could change the escape character to a backslash, but I don't know how to do that so...

Presumably the other characters mentioned in the PHP docs for db2_escape_string (http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-escape-string.php) would still need to be escaped with a backslash.

Rather than trying to replicate the functionality of the db2_escape_string function in a preg_replace call, I think you're best calling db2_escape_string and then fixing up the apostrophes that have been escaped with a backslash.

This seemed to work for me (though I'm at a loss to understand why I needed 5 backslashes instead of 3):

```
$var = db2_escape_string($var);
$var = preg_replace('/\\\\\'/',"''",$var);
```

Comment: Interesting thought . . . I may be misunderstanding your answer. It sounds like you're saying replace the apostrophes with backslashes? If so, that would be the opposite of what I'm looking for. DB2 on i wants an apostrophe as an escape character instead of a backslash. Still you've given me an idea to test out . . . . running db2_escape_string, then doing a str_replace to swap the backslashes with apostrophes.

Comment: The preg_replace pattern above replaces \' with '' - you are right that str_replace should be able to achieve the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the pattern. That may come in handy in other spots.